# ¿Como llamo un objeto personalizado (checkbox) a un formulario en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing, checkbox, jframe

Tengo una clase donde cree un checkbox personalizado para mi programa:

```
public CheckBox() {
    this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/uncheck.png")));
    this.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/check.png")));
    this.setOpaque(false);
    
    this.setForeground(new Color(102,0,51));
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    
    this.setSize(548, 30);
    
    this.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    
    Font ArialRounded = new Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    this.setFont(ArialRounded);
    
}
```

Luego en el botón donde se hace click se llama la función anterior, pero cuando lo ejecuto no pasa nada.

```
private void addNoteTxtMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        

    String texto = AddChekAriaLbl.getText();
    
    if (!"".equals(texto)) {
        
      CheckBox abrir = new CheckBox();
      abrir.setVisible(true);
        
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panelMenu, "El mensaje es: "+ texto);
    }else{
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panelMenu, "Ingrese texto en la casilla");
    }
}
```

Aquí dejo una imagen de la interfaz para que se entienda un poco más.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUkjX.png

Si alguien sabe como puedo llamarla directamente desde el botón agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Que tendría que pasar exactamente? Si la clase CheckBox hereda de JCheckBox al llamar a la función solo estas inicializando un nuevo CheckBox, pero no lo estas agregando a ningún panel por lo que no debería mostrarse. Cuando realizas un "setVisible" se muestra o se oculta solo si esta en un panel o cualquier otro contenedor.

Comment: Hola @Nika, entiendo que en algún lugar tienes algo así como: boton.addMouseListener( new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked( java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt ) {
                addNoteTxtMouseClicked( evt );
            }
        });   si no es así, deberías agregarlo, si no es este tu problema, trata de subir todo el código que consideres que es necesario para entender el problema.